# MongoDB and mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I studing NodeJs and for the first time , i must used mongoose package for insert data into MongoDB. Into mongoose, what are "Schema" and "Module"? 
I don't really understand follow code:

```
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = new Schema ({ 
       Firstname: String,
       Lastname: String
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var person1 = Person {(
       Firstname: "...",
       Lastname: "..."

)};
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Mongoose starts with a Schema. Each schema maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that collection.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = new Schema ({ 
   firstname: {type: String, required: true},
   lastname: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

To use our schema definition, we need to convert our personSchema into a Model we can work with. To do so, we pass it into:

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

To more information [enter link description here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: In easy words: Schema is a schema that contain a structure that the  documents must follow and the model is an "schema model" that inherit the structure of schema and i use this for defining a document.